# Python : printing number sequences from nested loops

Tags: python, for-loop

I know it seems very basic and easy, and I'm sorry if I'm wasting everybody's time, but I'm stuck and it's been hours now.

I have 4 loops, and in the end I must print all the numbers from 1 to the end. It will  be moe clear after you see the code:

```
for a in range (0,7):
    for b in range (1,118):
        for c in range (0,7):
            for d in range (1,118):
                print(...)
```

What I expect is :

```
1
2
3
...
383292
```

where 383292=118*118*7*4

Keep in mind that I really need these 4 loops as they are shown.

What should I put inside the print? I feel so stupid right now because it seems to be a simple math problem but I can't seem to figure out the solution.
Thanks a lot.

EDIT: to answers to all the comments, let's say I have this:

```
for a in range (0,2):
    for b in range (1,3):
        for c in range (0,2):
            for d in range (1,3):
                print(...)
```

I want to have as output:

```
1
2
3
...
24
```

I need to find some operations to do on a,b,c and d to have my results. I hope it is a bit clearer.

Comment: Do you want to print the number just one time? or multiple times?

Comment: Maybe start with a small range, and provide `input` and `output` ?

Comment: Not quite clear from your question but do you just need to declare `e = 1` at the start, print e, and then `e += 1` after the print?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you can put print statement below each `for` loop declaration, but then you'll have duplicated values. Another thing is the question, if you need these values to be ordered or not. Please provide clear input and output as @hansolo suggested.

Comment: Did you try a simple "counter" variable like David Buck suggested? Your math was wrong -- you will print 16 times because 16 == 2*2*2*2, which is the ranges you selected. You edited out the multiplication which shows your intent.

Comment: `itertools.product` would be a good option here as it roughly equivalent to nested for-loops - at 4 or more levels of nested for loops the code starts to get ugly.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I guess it's the easiest solution to my problem. I'll try

Comment: @Peter - can you answer the question - are you just expecting the output to be a sequence of all integers from 1 to the max number? If so a simple counter as I mentioned above will be simplest. If not, are you fully clear that `a in range (0,2)` will only produce values of `a` of 0 and 1, but not 2?

Comment: @DavidBuck I needed a counter but I needed to use a, b, c and d for that. TheHowlingHoaschd gave the answer I was looking for. Thanks again everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Yeah, the counter may be easier in most cases, but this is cooler!)

You need to know the amount of outputs that occur per iteration of each loop.

Assuming your loops have this many cycles:

```
cycles_a = 7
cycles_b = 117
cycles_c = 4
cycles_d = 117
```

You have outputs:

```
outputs_d = 1
outputs_c = outputs_d * cycles_d
outputs_b = outputs_c * cycles_c
outputs_a = outputs_b * cycles_b
```

If you run this loop:

```
for a in range(0,cycles_a):
    for b in range(0,cycles_b):
        for c in range(0,cycles_c):
            for d in range(0,cycles_d):
                print(d*outputs_d + c*outputs_c + b*outputs_b + a*outputs_a)
```

You will print:

```
0
1
...
<7*117*4*117 - 1>
```

If you want to start by printing 1, add one to the formula.

If your ranges start at 1 instead of 0, use `(a-1)`/`(b-1)`/`(c-1)`/`(d-1)` in the formula.

Comment: That's exacctly what I wanted, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

First, there is the straightforward and direct way:

```py
counter = 1
for a in range (0,7):
    for b in range (1,118):
        for c in range (0,7):
            for d in range (1,118):
                print(counter)
                counter += 1
```

---

If we want to not do that, then we might note that it's as though you are writing a number in a mixed base (as opposed to base 10). It sort of seems like your number is in the form

```
A B C D
| | | |__ base 118
| | |____ base 7
| |______ base 118
|________ base 7
```

To convert a number from this mixed base to base 10, you do

```py
def convert(a, b, c, d):
    return d + 7 * c + 118 * 7 * b + 7 * 118 * 7 * a
```

(Or you reverse the digits and endian-ness).

So then you might do

```py
for a in range (0,7):
    for b in range (118):
        for c in range (0,7):
            for d in range (118):
                print(d + 7 * c + 118 * 7 * b + 7 * 118 * 7 * a)
```

Comment: Now that's a clever way of getting around the ambiguities of the question. The counter won't end on the right number, but the second part of this answer will actually answer the original question, taking some liberties with the elipses to cover up problems in the original problem statement, and meet the "function of a,b,c,d" stipulation. You may have some math errors and start and end on the wrong numbers.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution (in the format you are doing it) would be:

```
counter = 0 
myrange = lambda x: range(1,x+1)

for a in myrange(118):
    for b in myrange(118):
        for c in myrange(7):
            for d in myrange(4):
                counter+= 1 
                print('counter %d gives: %d = %d * %d * %d * %d'%(counter,a*b*c*d,a,b,c,d))
```

`myrange` runs a command starting at 1 and ending at x < maxnum+1 (ie. your max number).

The print uses cstyle formatting where `%d` is an integer `%s` is a string etc and subs in the arguments after `%`.

This produces:

```
counter 1 gives: 1 = 1 * 1 * 1 * 1

...

counter 389869 gives: 97468 = 118 * 118 * 7 * 1
counter 389870 gives: 194936 = 118 * 118 * 7 * 2
counter 389871 gives: 292404 = 118 * 118 * 7 * 3
counter 389872 gives: 389872 = 118 * 118 * 7 * 4
```

Alternatively, you can save the values in a list and print them one at a time.

```
myrange = lambda x: range(1,x+1)
output=[]
for a in myrange(118):
    for b in myrange(118):
        for c in myrange(7):
            for d in myrange(4):
                output.append(a*b*c*d)

for i in output:
   print(i)
```

This gives:

```
1
...
250632
334176
97468
194936
292404
389872
```

If you need the values to be sored in size, you can do

```
output.sort()

for i in output:
   print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the easier way is:

```
res = 0
for a in range (0,2):
    for b in range (1,3):
        for c in range (0,2):
            for d in range (1,3):
                res += 1
                print(res)
```

but it prints a max of 16 numbers, not 24.
You should start counting from 0 to n, or instead of `(1, 3)` you should write `(1,4)` if you want your cycle to repeat 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is using a generator:

```
>>> def infinite_counter(n=0):
        while True:
            n += 1
            yield n

>>> counter = infinite_counter()

>>> for i in range(3):
       for j in range(2):
           print(next(counter))
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

The `itertools.product` is even better if you don't really need the ugly 4+ levels of nested `for` loops (if you are discarding the values in the iterables and just want the counting):

```
>>> for i, _ in enumerate(product(range(3), range(2))):
        print(i+1)
1
2
3
4
5
6
```